# Linking and using local UI module in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Disclaimer; I am new to react & react-native. I've downloaded a UI module and am attempting to use it in my project. This is what the folder structure looks like:

```
├── myProject
│   ├── README.md
│   └── src
│       └── client
│           └── {actual react-native project}
└── react-native-ui-module
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json
    └── src
```

I've added `react-native-ui-module` to `myProject/src/client/package.json` like so:

```
"react-native-ui-module": "file:../../../react-native-ui-module",
```

From there, I've executed the following command:

```
$ npm install
$ react-native link
```

I can see the module in `node_modules` after the above steps.

I've expected to then use the module like so:

```
import { Button } from 'react-native-ui-module';
```

However, I'm getting an error that states that the `Module`react-native-ui-module` does not exist in the Haste module map. I've tried following the error message's suggestion, which is:

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.

I've also tried using relative and absolute paths in the import statement. Is there a better way of importing and installing the module? And what other troubleshooting steps can I take to actually use the module?

Also, to clarify; this is a module that I've purchased and manually downloaded, so it's not available from npmjs.

Comment: Have you tried linking it manually?

Comment: I recommend to link it manually following the module instructions.

Comment: How do I link it manually? I came across this article: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios, but there isn't any native code to be linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short thing you can do, considering your current situation, is to copy the ui module into the node_modules of your {actual react-native project}, then the ui module will be available for you to use in the imports, in this way you don't even need to add the module into your package.json, but this way is just for testing what the ui module can do.

The correct way is to find this ui module in the npm site, and use the command `npm install --save [name-of-the-ui-module]`, then ui module will be available for you to use in your imports.

**(Updated considering comments bellow)**

To avoid Headaches with npm, considering that your library is not in the npm repository, you can also include this library in a lib folder into your project, and use it like you were using any other component.

Comment: So, the module is indeed in `node_modules` after `npm install && react-native link`. I've tried using that path as well to import it, but still no luck. The module in question is also one that I've purchased and downloaded so it's not available on npmjs. I've updated my question to clarify this.

Comment: Well, it should work just by putting the project into your node_modules folder, and then importing like this `import { Button } from 'react-native-ui-module';`.  This way you don't need to do a `npm install`, you dont need to do a `react-native link`, as well, this will try to link native code, what is not your case. One thing you could do is to check if this ui module has an index.js file that exports the components you are looking for (Button, Text...).

Comment: It does have an `index.js` file that exports the components. Does that change things?

Comment: It changes nothing, it's expected. To avoid Headaches with npm, considering that your library is not in the npm repository, you can also include this library in a lib folder into your project, and use it like you were using any other component

Comment: ok - I ended up just adding it in the source code. If you'd like to update your answer to include that information I'll be glad to mark it as correct.

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm glad that you could solve your problem.